# basic program to add to txt file list

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

Say I have a list such as...

apples
milk
bread
cheese

and I wanted to be able to drop that list and convert it to something like this

"apples" and
"milk" and
"bread" and
"cheese" and

what would be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = 'apples milk bread cheese';

const newText = `"${text.split(' ').join('" and "')}"`;

console.log(newText);
```